# Issue in drag and drop functionality in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a JavaScript drag and drop code,

I have two classes `div1` for drop and `div2` for drag.

I have set `position` of these two classes in CSS according to `viewport` `width` and `height` and is mandatory here.

The problem is, when I drag and drop `div2` to `div1`, the element is not going and get placed inside `div1`.

How to make the class `div2` dragged and get placed inside class `div1`?

```js
function allowDrop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
  ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");

  console.log(data);
  assignedTabName = document.getElementById(data).className;
  console.log(assignedTabName);

  ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));

}
```

```css
.div1 {
  border: 2px solid black;
  position: absolute;
  width: 23vw;
  height: 10vh;
  left: 10vw;
  bottom: 80vh;
}

.div2 {
  border: 2px solid black;
  position: fixed;
  width: 14vw;
  height: 12vh;
  left: 0vw;
  bottom: 60vh;
  background-color: #FFFF00;
}
```

```html
<div class="div1" id="drop1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
<br>
<div class="div2" id="drag1" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">
  <p width="336" height="69">hello</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your positioning rules of the divs is the problem. If you remove the `position: absolute` from the CSS of `.div1`, and the `position: relative` from the CSS of `.div2`, then the drag-and-drop seems to work as expected.

```js
function allowDrop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
  ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");

  console.log(data);
  assignedTabName = document.getElementById(data).className;
  console.log(assignedTabName);

  ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));

}
```

```css
.div1 {
  border: 2px solid black;
  width: 23vw;
  height: 10vh;
  left: 10vw;
  bottom: 80vh;
}

.div2 {
  border: 2px solid black;
  width: 14vw;
  height: 12vh;
  left: 0vw;
  bottom: 60vh;
  background-color: #FFFF00;
}
```

```html
<div class="div1" id="drop1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
<br>
<div class="div2" id="drag1" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">
  <p width="336" height="69">hello</p>
</div>
```